# Cannot write to Z channel using OpenEXR

Tags: hdr, openexr, hdrimages

I'm trying the read/write examples in the following official documentation:

[ReadingAndWritingImageFiles.pdf](http://www.openexr.com/ReadingAndWritingImageFiles.pdf)

But I can't write to the Z channel. The image is all black in exrdisplay(the official EXR viewer) even the exposure is max.

If I replace 'Z' with 'R' then I can see a reddish image using exrdisplay.